# Change data type of QT GUI Vector sink in gnu radio companion

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm running gnuradio 3.7.11 and I'd like to dump the bytes output of a GFSK demodulation block into a vector sink. However, the QT GUI vector sink block in gnuradio companion seems to be a float type only. I know I can use different vector sink types in code but, Is there any way to switch the type of a vector sink to bytes in the companion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The qt GUI vector sink simply doesn't exist for 8 bit integers.

Simply convert to float using the existing conversion blocks.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks